# react - how to print a pdf file getting from an url

Tags: node.js, reactjs, pdf, printing

In one of the pages in my project, There are two buttons namely "Process" and "Print". When I click on Print button it will trigger an API call and generate a pdf file and return it's url in the response. Url's format is something like below.

```
https://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf
```

So when I click on the print button, i want print dialog to popup to print the document which can be accessed using that url.
I have tried many solutions but I couldn't find a way to solve this issue. Some of the solutions that i have tried are mentioned below.

```
const handlePrint2 = () => {
    window.open(url, "PRINT", "height=400,width=600");
  };
```

```
const handlePrintPDF2 = () => {
  const printWindow = window.open(url);
  
  if (printWindow) {
    printWindow.print();
  }
};
```